# «"Гений" — незримый, бесплотный дух добра или зла. В. И. Даль». Правильное цитирование

Tags: пунктуация, оформление-текста, цитирование

Третьего января (в день памяти Александра Абдулова) смотрела фильм «Гений» и обратила внимание на самые [**первые кадры**](https://filmix.co/kriminal/34783-geniy-1991.html).

**"Гений" — незримый, бесплотный дух добра или зла. В. И. Даль**

Поначалу просто подумалось, что слово "гений" не нужно было брать в кавычки.

Потом я обнаружила собственно в [словаре Даля](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/enc2p/224710) следующее:
**ГЕНИЙ**
муж., лат. **незримый, бесплотный дух, добрый или злой**; дух-покровитель человека, добрый и злой.

Подскажите, правильно ли ТАК оформлять цитирование? Если нет — то **как** нужно было грамотно написать в самом начале фильма?
Мне кажется, что при таком оформлении еще и смысл выражения поменялся. Или мне только кажется?

Answer (score 3):

Вы наблюдательны, я вот не обратила внимания. Конечно неверный эпиграф, вернее, **некорректно оформленный**. Смысл-то они вложили верный, ведь имелась в виду негативная направленность таланта, а вот Даля они передали вольно и не имели права указывать на его авторство: или уж целиком фразу писать, или от третьего лица.

Можно было бы оформить так: По Далю, гений — незримый, бесплотный дух добра или зла. **Без кавычек и сноски** после текста.

Что они имели в виду, взяв слово гений в кавычки, непонятно, то ли хотели воспроизвести название фильма, то ли то, что это слово, а не сам гений.

Насчёт **изменения смысла** цитаты из Даля. Цитата охватывает три смысла: дух-покровитель, добрый или злой; творческий дар; человек, обладающий даром. Они взяли  ту часть, которая им выгодна, указывает на негативную энергию. Это нормально: герой гениален, но его гениальность от злого духа.

Я не вижу извращения Даля. Меня возмущает только то, что современные авторы вольно обращаются с чужими текстами. Указываешь Даля, так и пиши его точное высказывание, а если только смысл, тогда так и скажи: "по словам Даля", "как говорил Даль" и т.д. Русский язык предоставляет нам разнообразные возможности передачи чужой речи.

Comment: Насчёт изменения смысла. Думаю, Римма имела в виду другое: добрый дух — это совсем не то же, что дух добра. Как, скажем, мудрый или красивый бог не обязан быть богом мудрости или красоты.

Comment: Ну, не знаю, бог и дух - разное восприятие. Для меня добрый дух - тот дух, который несёт добро, значит дух добра. Это ж не существо со своим характером, это сгусток энергии. Это его миссия, добрый дух несёт только добро, а бог - верховное существо, он сам может быть каким угодно по характеру, а вот существительное как определение его - это территория его власти.